# Fix non-english alphabet in indexing

Tags: indexing, languages

When I try to index non-english alphabet, it does not sort the letters according to the alphabet.

For example,

```
\index{\v{s}umnik}
```

or equivalently

```
\index{šumnik}
```

puts the "š" after "z", but in Slovenian alphabet, "š" (charon "s") comes after "s". In Slovenian alphabet the letter "š" is a letter on it's own (just as "a", "b" or "c"), it's not just the letter "s" with an accent.

```
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
```

does not fix this.

Comment: you don't say, or show an example but I assume you are using makeindex? (latex itself never sorts)

Comment: you can use `\v{s}umnik\index{szumnik@\v{s}umnik}` so it sorts after s although the `\indexspace` grouping will show it as s not as a new letter.

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can have a look at my `esindex`, but it doesn't create a group: https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/esindex/esindex.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Use `Xindy` for indexing. Run it with:

`texindy --language=slovenian --codepage=utf8 test.idx`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\index{šumnik}
\index{sss}
\index{ttt}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]